# How to remove statusbar from messageviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am sending sms programmatically from my view controller but now it is showing me statusbar and vertical black line

my code:

```
- (IBAction)SendTextBtnTapped:(id)sender {
    [self sendSMS:@"Body of SMS..." recipientList:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil]];
}


- (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSArray *)recipients
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = bodyOfMessage;    
        controller.recipients = recipients;
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }    
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled)
        NSLog(@"Message cancelled");
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent)
        NSLog(@"Message sent");  
    else 
        NSLog(@"Message failed");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this line

```
controller.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

**OR** add this line after present MessageViewController like bellow..

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

**OR** for whole this viewController use bellow loginin `viewWillAppear:` paste this code..

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have done initially status bar hidden = yes in my plist, does i have to still put this code in my appdelegate

Comment: @hckr try this now dude.. i put 3 option in which every code for different ouput just take which you want dude.. i hope this help you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [wantsFullScreenLayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = bodyOfMessage;    
    controller.recipients = recipients;
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    controller.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;  //<== add this
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```